# Change the response body in apache based on request method

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have an apache server that I'd like to configure to behave differently when the request method is OPTIONS. This is a static site so doing it in a scripting language isn't possible. In my case when the request method is OPTIONS I'd like apache to simply return the standard response headers but skip the body altogether. Is such a thing possible via the .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by using mod_rewrite and creating an empty `blank.html` file:

```
<Limit OPTIONS>
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blank.html [QSA,L]
</Limit>
```